# Tips on implementing XMPP Chat on Webpage - Lightweight

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, xmpp, chat

I want to ask your opinion on implementing a web-based "chat widget" on a website.

Here is how I'm currently doing it:

- OpenFire (lastest Beta)
- Tigase Messenger XMPP library / webclient
- htttp://messenger.tigase.org/

The Tigase Messenger was written using the Google Web Toolkit. It took a LOT of modification meet my requirements... but overall it's working OK.

Features that I need:

1. groupchat tabs
2. group chat roster
3. double-click a group chat participant to initiate point-to-point chat
4. (nice to have) highlighting, play sound when message comes in

Here are some screenshots to see what it looks like.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9vgL.jpg

**Now, my here are the problems I have with this**

First off, it loads slow as anything. Maybe it's all the javascript, GWT, who knows... secondly, it's a pain writing everything in GWT. The rest of the webapp is ASP .NET 4.0. on IIS7. It would be a lot easier on me developing in one IDE (and one language), instead of switching my brain between Visual Studio 2010 and Eclipse (Java).

I started looking in to alternatives. After some searches here, I found agsXMPP (htttp://www.ag-software.de/agsxmpp-sdk/). Looks like a asp .NET library.

Really, I just wanted to bounce my ideas off you guys... if you were in my shoes, and wanted to develop a (relatively) simple XMPP based chat, using ASP .NET, supporting group chat and point-to-point -- how would YOU go about it?

Any tips, links, experience would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

-Josh

Comment: By the way, I've been looking into strophe and jsjac. Look like there is a LOT of info for these two. Any experience out there using these javascript libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Strophe](http://code.stanziq.com/strophe/) is pretty cool.  Get Jack's [book](http://professionalxmpp.com/) also, and you'll be up and running in no time.

Comment: Hey Everyone, just wanted to follow up. I bought this book and its the JAM. Really great... I totally recommend it.